# How to stretch row height of android GridView?

Tags: android

I am having one gridview.In that Dynamically added component and height of the component is vary. so i want row height of grid view is maximum height of component.
Please somebody help me.

Comment: My code of GridView like following :-   <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:columnWidth="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth">
    </GridView>

Answer (score 0):

if you have components of vary height , this example project will suit best to your problem
 https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid